# Battery information c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem with the battery information extraction in C #. Looking for:

- design capacity
- full charge capacity
- current capacity
- alert level
- critical bias
- charge rate

The rest of the information extracted from `SystemInformation.PowerStatus` and
`SELECT from CIM_Battery` class.

Problem that many properties of this class are no longer supported.

Where should I look for the rest of the information?

Comment: Buttery status for what divice? Hanheld, laptop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945986/find-out-battery-status-in-c-sharp-or-net

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Win32_Battery class, [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kirtan007/get-laptop-battery-status-using-C-Sharp-and-wmi/) is an example and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the Win32_Battery class on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

For handhelds you can use the class. At least i use it for years.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

namespace uti {
public class Power {

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "KernelIoControl", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool KernelIoControl(int dwIoControlCode, System.IntPtr lpInBuf, int nInBufSize, byte[] lpOutBuf, int nOutBufSize, ref int lpBytesReturned);

    private const int FILE_ANY_ACCESS = 0;
    private const int FILE_DEVICE_HAL = 257;
    private const int METHOD_BUFFERED = 0;
    private const int IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT = (FILE_DEVICE_HAL << 16) | (FILE_ANY_ACCESS << 14) | (15 << 2) | METHOD_BUFFERED;

    public static bool DeviceReset() {
        int cb = 0;
        return KernelIoControl(IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT, System.IntPtr.Zero, 0, null, 0, ref cb);
    }


    private struct SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX {
        public byte ACLineStatus;
        public byte BatteryFlag;
        public byte BatteryLifePercent;
        public byte Reserved1;
        public uint BatteryLifeTime;
        public uint BatteryFullLifeTime;
        public byte Reserved2;
        public byte BackupBatteryFlag;
        public byte BackupBatteryLifePercent;
        public byte Reserved3;
        public uint BackupBatteryLifeTime;
        public uint BackupBatteryFullLifeTime;
    }

    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    extern static private bool GetSystemPowerStatusEx(ref SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX sps);

    public enum enACLineStatus {
        Offline = 0,
        Online = 1,
        Backuppower = 2,
        Unknownstatus = 255
    }

    [FlagsAttribute]
    public enum enBatteryFlag {
        High = 1,
        Low = 2,
        Critical = 4,
        Charging = 8,
        Nosystembattery = 128,
        Unknownstatus = 255
    }


    static enACLineStatus _ACLineStatus = 0;

    public static enACLineStatus ACLineStatus {
        get {
            return _ACLineStatus;
        }
    }

    static enBatteryFlag _BatteryFlag = 0;

    public static enBatteryFlag BatteryFlag {
        get {
            return _BatteryFlag;
        }
    }

    static byte _BatteryLifePercent = 0;

    public static byte BatteryLifePercent {
        get {
            return _BatteryLifePercent;
        }
    }

    static byte _Reserved1 = 0;

    public static byte Reserved1 {
        get {
            return _Reserved1;
        }
    }

    static uint _BatteryLifeTime = 0;

    public static uint BatteryLifeTime {
        get {
            return _BatteryLifeTime;
        }
    }

    static uint _BatteryFullLifeTime = 0;

    public static uint BatteryFullLifeTime {
        get {
            return _BatteryFullLifeTime;
        }
    }

    static byte _Reserved2 = 0;

    public static byte Reserved2 {
        get {
            return _Reserved2;
        }
    }

    static enBatteryFlag _BackupBatteryFlag = 0;

    public static enBatteryFlag BackupBatteryFlag {
        get {
            return _BackupBatteryFlag;
        }
    }

    static byte _BackupBatteryLifePercent = 0;

    public static byte BackupBatteryLifePercent {
        get {
            return _BackupBatteryLifePercent;
        }
    }

    static byte _Reserved3 = 0;

    public static byte Reserved3 {
        get {
            return _Reserved3;
        }
    }

    static uint _BackupBatteryLifeTime = 0;

    public static uint BackupBatteryLifeTime {
        get {
            return _BackupBatteryLifeTime;
        }
    }

    static uint _BackupBatteryFullLifeTime = 0;

    public static uint BackupBatteryFullLifeTime {
        get {
            return _BackupBatteryFullLifeTime;
        }
    }

    public static void Refresh() {
        SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX sps = new SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX();

        bool bRet = GetSystemPowerStatusEx(ref sps);
        if (!bRet)
            return;

        _ACLineStatus =
            (enACLineStatus)
            sps.ACLineStatus;
        _BatteryFlag =
            (enBatteryFlag)
            sps.BatteryFlag;
        _BatteryLifePercent =
            sps.BatteryLifePercent;
        _Reserved1 =
            sps.Reserved1;
        _BatteryLifeTime =
            sps.BatteryLifeTime;
        _BatteryFullLifeTime =
            sps.BatteryFullLifeTime;
        _Reserved2 =
            sps.Reserved2;
        _BackupBatteryFlag =
            (enBatteryFlag)
            sps.BackupBatteryFlag;
        _BackupBatteryLifePercent =
            sps.BackupBatteryLifePercent;
        _Reserved3 =
            sps.Reserved3;
        _BackupBatteryLifeTime =
            sps.BackupBatteryLifeTime;
        _BackupBatteryFullLifeTime =
            sps.BackupBatteryFullLifeTime;
    }


    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int SetSystemPowerState(string psState, int StateFlags, int    Options);

    const int POWER_STATE_ON = 0x00010000;
    const int POWER_STATE_OFF = 0x00020000;
    const int POWER_STATE_SUSPEND = 0x00200000;
    const int POWER_FORCE = 4096;
    const int POWER_STATE_RESET = 0x00800000;
   }
 }
```