# Battery information

Tags: c#, msdn, battery, openhardwaremonitor

I'm adding some features to Open hardware Monitor. I have found a cool class for C# to read the battery info.

I need three (and maybe more in the future):
Battery temperature
Battery voltage
battery Life remaining.

Now I have found some classes for C# with this information. But how can I use those classes. 
I will use the battery class from Microsoft. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.spot.hardware.battery(v=vs.102).aspx).

I does not get the class to work when I call it (can't call it).

Or if you guys have some C# api with battery info that I can use please let me know.

Comment: What did you try? What error did you get?

Comment: The MSDN document you have linked is not for regular computers.  It is for microcontrollers that run .Net micro framework.

Comment: Ok didn't know that's for microcontrollers tnx. But I can find the remaining life with PowerStatus class. But can't find anything for temperature and voltage. Do you know some source to read this information?

Comment: You should use `WMI`. See the link below:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945986/find-out-battery-status-in-c-sharp-or-net